# Safari web browser 5.1.7 does not include an option to stop Auto-Refresh

Tags: safari, safari-extension

I have safari 5.1.7 , but under the Debug menu I can not find any option to stop the auto-refresh. I try un-checking the "Use multi-process tabs", but it did not solve the auto-refresh problem. any idea about disabling auto-refresh inside safari 5.1.7 ?

Comment: You could perhaps do some trickery with SafariBeforeNavigateEvent?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834362/get-url-and-page-title-data-from-safarinavigateevent

Answer (score 0):

Today I inadvertently discovered a way to stop this annoying behavior, even though it does not qualify as a real fix, it is a method of suppressing the behavior by taking a simple action every time prior to switching out from Safari or another browser.  Not ideal, but it does give you control (finally) of the browser such that the behavior is suppressed.  The link to the answer is here:

https://discussions.apple.com/message/25254749#25254749